# Automatically inject 360° 3D metadata into a video with a Bash script

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, cygwin

So, I have a Cygwin script I made which concats several videos into a single video with different variations, and I want to inject stereoscopic 3D metadata into the videos through the script so I don't have to inject each video separately using Google's injector tool. The videos are all 360° videos with top/bottom 3D and standard stereo audio rather than spacial audio, and in an MP4 container. Is there any way that I can either inject the needed 3D metadata using FFmpeg so I can upload it to YouTube as a 360VR video, or use the source code of Google's injector tool or some other tool in order to inject the metadata the same way that Google's injector tool would so it's supported as a 360° 3D video by YouTube?

Also, will the injector tool automatically move the MOV atom to the beginning of the file (if the injector tool is used) or will I still need to use `-movflags +faststart` in FFmpeg? The videos are kind of big and apparently using FFmpeg to concat several video files together and copy the stream codecs with `-movflags +faststart` and then injecting the metadata using Google's Spherical Media tool is three times longer than just using FFmpeg in the same way but without `-movflags +faststart`, so if there was a fast way to do this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

for mp4 you can try `ffmpeg -i [input].mp4 -vcodec libx264 -x264opts frame-packing=4 [output].mp4`, but it will transcode your video. I am not sure if it will keep 360° metadata.